# Python Output Bigger String than Format Specification

Tags: python, format

Python outputs formats greater than the size in the format statement. The following statements specify a string length of 4 characters but the output increases to fit the string. How is this managed within code when specific layouts are required?

```
print('#{:4.4}#'.format('xylophone'))
print('#{:4.5}#'.format('xylophone'))
print('#{:4.10}#'.format('xylophone'))
```

Output:

```
#xylo#
#xylop#
#xylophone#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the format statement `{:X.Y}`.

The value `X` is the *padding*. The output string will be at least `X` characters wide, but can be more. The format command will add whitespace to the output string to make up the difference in length if the input string is shorter than `X`. **`X` will always be the *minimum width* of the formatted field.**

The value `Y` is the *truncation*. The output string will contain no more than `Y` characters from the input string. **`Y` will always be the *maximum width* of the formatted field.**

If `Y` > `X`, then the output string will be at least `X` characters and up to `Y` characters long, as your examples show. If `X` > `Y`, then the formatted string will contain up to the first `Y` characters from the input string with whitespace to pad the formatted string to be `X` characters wide if needed.

If a field in a layout must be a specific width, then set `X` and `Y` both to the width of the field and it will output correctly.

Examples:

```
print('#{:.4}#'.format('xylophone')) #include up to 4 characters (no minimum width specified)
#xylo#

print('#{:10.4}#'.format('xylophone')) #include up to 4 characters, but make the field at least 10 characters wide
#xylo      #
```

Comment: Excellent explanation!